# CMake not finding GL/glew.h

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glew

I'm using CLion under pop_OS! 20.04 and am currently trying to get CMake to work with GLEW because I want to follow [these tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) to get started with OpenGL. I'm relatively new to C/C++ and completely new to CMake.

I installed the `libgl1-mesa-dev`,`libglew-dev`,`libglfw3`,`libglfw3-dev` packages with `apt-get install` and the `glew.h` is located alongside the other GL header files in `/usr/include/GL`.

When trying to compile a simple program:

```c
#include <GL/glew.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

cmake can't find the headerfile:

```
test/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <GL/glew.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Do I have to manually add these header files in `CMakeLists.txt` for cmake to find them? I tried like a dozen different suggestions but I didn't get it to work. For example, I tried

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_libraries(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(test GLEW::GLEW)
```

but this results in

```
CMake Error at /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS GLEW_LIBRARIES)
```

Is this somehow a problem with CLion and I need to include libraries into my project in a different manner? Or am I using cmake in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last try was nearly right.

Forget about `include_directories` and `link_libraries` commands. All it needs when doing modern CMake is an `add_executable(test main.cpp)` followed by a `target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE GLEW::glew)` command. The target `GLEW::glew` (case matters here) bundles all compile definitions, include directories, libraries, and further settings that are needed to compile and link your example.

Your CMakeLists.txt would now look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

add_executable(myTest main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myTest PRIVATE GLEW::glew)
```

Edit: Just noticed, that GLEW::GLEW can also be used.

Comment: That again tells me `Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS GLEW_LIBRARIES)`. I think it's somehow a problem with my glew installation.

Comment: Does it work when running CMake manually, e.g. `cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir> -G "Unix Makefiles"` followed by a `cmake --build <builddir> --target all --config Release`?

Comment: It does! Just the first `cmake` followed by a `make` in the `<builddir>` works. So the problem is with the CLion compiler, I guess.

Comment: Okay, so the CLion Issue was fixed by not using the flatpak but instead installing it via the JetBrains Toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @vre is OK. I only add how to find it yourself.

First, run

```
cmake --help-module-list
```

and look for GLEW. Under Linux, you can simplify this step to

```
cmake --help-module-list | grep -i Glew
```

where `-i` stands for "case insesitive match", as we usually don't remember if it's GLEW or perhaps Glew. Once you know the module name, you can ask for the specific help related to just this module:

```
cmake --help-module FindGLEW
```

The answer is there. Read and enjoy!

PS. There's no need to memorize this answer. All can be reduced to `cmake --help`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually went through all help pages i could find before asking here. The problem turned out to be be that the flatpak install of CLion didn't find the library. I reinstalled it another way and it worked fine.